# Show that, if $M$ is an $nxm$ matrix that $|M|^2$ = $tr(M^TM)$

Tags: linear-algebra

No Idea how to do this one. All I know is that, if a matrix is diagonal, then the determinant equals the trace.

Comment: What is $|M|$? I don't know.

Comment: determinant of M.I agree , it is weird.. I would prefer just det(M).

Comment: Only square matrices have determinants.  Should $M$ be $m \times m$?

Comment: Yeah, let me take a look...

this problem is copied straight out of the book, so maybe this |M| means something else, hold on...

Comment: Nope, you're right, it's NOT determinant.

$|A|^2$ for matrix $A$ is the length of the matrix, which is the sum of the squares of all its entries.

Comment: Suggestion: take a $2\times2$ example, say $M=\pmatrix{a&b\cr c&d\cr}$ and calculate the RHS.  This will probably suggest to you what $|M|$ actually means **and** give you a pretty good idea how to prove the equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think about the upper left element of $M^TM$, it is the sum of the squares of all the elements of the first column of $M$.  Each diagonal element in $M^TM$ is the sum of the squares of its column of $M$, so the trace of $M^TM$ is the sum of the squares of all the elements of $M$

Comment: perfect, thanks!